# Cannot remove am from datetime

Tags: c#

I need to get the pc datetime without am or pm, so I did:

```
var pcDate = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"),"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but I get: 3/13/2018 2:51:39 AM

I need to get this format: 13/03/2018 14:52

Comment: What do you mean that you get 3/13/2018 2:51:39 AM. `pcDate` is a DateTime object and you haven't formatted anything.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You are taking a `DateTime`, converting it to a `string`, and then immediately converting it back to a `DateTime`.   Why do this?  It is wasted effort!

Comment: Keep in mind that a `DateTime` object does not have a format. It's just a point in time. You only use a format when converting the datetime from or to a human readable string.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you do `ToString` and again `ParseEact` ?

Can't you just:

```
var pcDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

> `HH` capital letter, 24 hour format

Comment: I need a datetime not a tostring

Comment: @hARRYPOTTER DateTime stores time as a number. It doesn't have a string representaiton until you call `ToString()` or look at it in the debugger. Quoting you: "I need to get this format: 13/03/2018 14:52" - that's a _string_ not a _datetime_.